iOS codesigning CI: errSecInternalComponent
Goal
Hi. I'm trying to update my iOS CI with new cert/key, because the app owner has changed and we have to start signing with new Apple account's credentials.
Before the process was working as expected. However, now it fails for an ambiguous reason.
What I do
this part practically hasn't changed from the previous process. Only the .key and .cer have changed
Prep work

generate a new key and CSR using openssl cli
submit the CSR to Apple and get it signed
download the signed cer
download the Apple CA cer
create a new keychain
into the keychain import:

Apple CA cer
my app cer (signed by Apple CA)
my PrivKey


create an Apple Distribution provisioning profile (also tried with iOS Distribution), link it to the certificate
download the provisioning profile

openssl req -new -key ios_key.key -out ios_csr.csr
openssl req -new -key ios_key.key -out csr.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=my@fancy-client.com, CN=Fancy Client, C=US"
## upload csr.certSigningRequest to Apple
## download the signed .cer
## link that .cer to profile
openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -in ios_signed.cer -inkey ios_key.key -passout pass:pass1 -out fancy-client-ci.p12 -name FancyClient

security create-keychain -p pass1 ci.keychain
security import fancy-client-ci.p12 -A -P pass1 -k /Users/ec2-user/Library/Keychains/ci.keychain-db

wget https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer
security import AppleWWDRCAG3.cer -A -P pass1 -k /Users/ec2-user/Library/Keychains/ci.keychain-db

When I open the ci.keychain using MacOS's KeychainAccess, the signed cert is shown as trusted (trust chain is complete) and the PrivKey is linked to it too.

Running CI
during the CI run I dump the keychain and profile to filesystem, unlock the keychain and provide path of the profile file to the fastlane's update_project_provisioning, then I issue the lane with build_app function.
Result
Code builds just fine, no issues there. Just like before changing the certs. But when it comes to signing, it fails with
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign B4C...411 --generate-entitlement-der /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<HIDDEN>-<HIDDEN>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/
nanopb.framework
note: Signing static framework with --generate-pre-encrypt-hashes (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<HIDDEN>-<HIDDEN>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/production/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

If I connect to the CI MAC server via ssh and try to run that signing command myself manually, I get the exact same error. Even if I add the key and cert to the login keychain, which are listed available via security list-keychains. Now here's the rub: if I run the exact same command in MAC Terminal via GUI (via VPN connection), it succeeds.
If I run security find-identity -p codesigning in either CI, ssh or GUI, I get the same identity listed in the output.
What gives...? I'm not a proficient MAC user; am I missing some nuances about the keychain's working principles?
EDIT
It even builds fine via ssh if I allow it to use the 'login' keychain (I've added the signing cert+key there too).
CI runners are launched after Mac server starts up, via ssh, in a tmux session
                tmux new-session -d -s bb-runners;
                tmux split-window -t bb-runners -h;
                tmux send-keys -t bb-runners:0.0 'cd ${DIR_RUNNER_0} && ./run-0.bash' C-m;
                tmux send-keys -t bb-runners:0.1 'cd ${DIR_RUNNER_1} && ./run-1.bash' C-m;

EDIT:
Another observation I've made is that if I copy the login keychain file, flush its contents and add the 3 artifacts (2 certs 1 key) I need for signing, codesign works. If I compare the working and non-working KCs' sizes, they are 29648 and 29636 respectively. I've compared the partitions, currently, they are the same (only apple: in the plist (checked by opening the keychains with less))

I may have figured this one out. I was missing the -T "" -T /usr/bin/codesign in the security import command.
This algorithm seems to be working:

KC_FILE="${PWD}/ci.keychain-db"
KC_PASS="pass1"
CER_CN="Fancy Client"
CER_EMAIL="my@fancy-client.com"
CER_C="US"

openssl req -new -key ios_key.key -out ios_csr.csr
openssl req -new -key ios_key.key -out csr.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=${CER_EMAIL}, CN=${CER_CN}, C=${CER_C:?US}"
## upload csr.certSigningRequest to Apple
## download the signed .cer
## link that .cer to profile
openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -in ios_signed.cer -inkey ios_key.key -passout pass:"${KC_PASS}" -out fancy-client-ci.p12 -name "${CER_CN}"

security create-keychain -p "${KC_PASS}" "${KC_FILE}"
security import fancy-client-ci.p12 -A -P "${KC_PASS}" -k "${KC_FILE}" -T "" -T /usr/bin/codesign
security set-key-partition-list -S apple: -k "${KC_PASS}" "${KC_FILE}"

wget https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer
security import AppleWWDRCAG3.cer -A -P "${KC_PASS}" -k "${KC_FILE}" -T "" -T /usr/bin/codesign

